# Excel: Can I make an "If"-formula use the condition when "true" without having to copy the formula to [value-if-true]?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Essentially, what I would like to do is shorten the following formula: `If(formula<>0;formula;"")`.

The "formula" in question is rather long and I was hoping there was a formula similar to `Iferror()` but for zeroes instead. The expected outcome of the formula is a string, so simply using `Max(0;formula)` won't work. It's an Index(Match()) formula, targeting an array with a few empty cells that technically meet the requirements and thus return 0's as answer.
The array used is updated frequently, so both the amount of cells used in the array and the amount of results change with every update, so I'd like to keep the result as dynamic as possible.

Is this possible or am I just better off hiding the zeroes with conditional formatting?

Comment: If there are no zeroes in the other results, you might use `=SUBSTITUTE(formula, 0, ""). Is that enouth?

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you very much.